# Why is ~/.vimrc not having an effect until I type ":so~/.vimrc"?

Tags: ubuntu, vim

I just want to change the tab size.  I know the file is loading because it shows up in :scriptnames and I included an echo which runs every time I open vim.  Why is ~/.vimrc not working automatically at startup of vim?

I am running the latest version of Ubuntu.

Contents of ~/.vimrc:

```
map <C-t><up> :tabr<cr>

map <C-t><down> :tabl<cr>

map <C-t><left> :tabp<cr>

map <C-t><right> :tabn<cr>

set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
echo "LOADED"
```

Comment: Your `~/.vimrc` is almost certainly sourced correctly but a filetype plugin may override your settings. Can you share your vimrc?

Comment: You mean the text in the file ~/.vimrc ?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: To find out what script is overriding your values, try `:verbose set tabstop? shiftwidth?`.

Comment: The :verbose command works for showing where mappings were defined as well. Check to see what mappings you have that start with `control-t` and where they were set:  `:verbose map <c-t>`

Comment: verbose set tabstop? returns "tabstop=8 Last set from ~/sortsession.vim" which is the session I am in.  If I do :so ~/.vimrc, it overrides that and then the tabs work, but if I quit and load the session again, I would have to call :so again.  The really confusing thing is, I can edit .vimrc (by adding another echo) and when I load the session, the new echo is displayed, but the set values are still being overwritten.

Comment: Yes, session files are loaded after `.vimrc` and tend to include _all_ the settings necessary to return Vim to the same state it was in when the session file was created.  This will override your `.vimrc` preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, saved sessions store all global config values and mappings, too. So, you need to explicitly source your changed `~/.vimrc` after loading a session, or re-create / edit your sessions.

If you don't change options and define mappings on the fly (only through `~/.vimrc` and plugins), it is not necessary to include this in your saved sessions. You can turn this off via:

```
:set sessionoptions-=options
```

As a nice side effect, your stored sessions will become much smaller in size.

Comment: Is it possible to permanently source a new .vimrc from an old session?

Comment: I would prefer the options in my answer, but you can do so via `:autocmd SessionLoadPost * source ~/.vimrc`